# Is "recherché" a commonly used word for "summary"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

In Czech, the word *rešerše*, i.e. the localized version of the French *recherché*, has two meanings:

1. the act of looking up information on a topic
2. a summary of the found information

Thus if one asked for a *rešerše*, he/she would expect to get a summary on the topic in question.

Now, I was just editing someone's English CV and found the word used frequently there, the person claims it is commonly used in English, too. Is that true?

Comment: When I lived in Calgary, Alberta, in 1970–1972, sportscasters covering Calgary Stampeders football games in the CFL would use the term _résumé_ to describe what a U.S. announcer would have called a _recap_, which is essentially a summary of the scoring and other highlights of the game. But I've never heard anyone in anglophone Canada or the United States use _recherché_ to refer to a summary.

Comment: No, that is not a common word in English. The corresponding word in English is "research" or possibly "results". One doesn't ask for a *recherché* in English.

Comment: I think you mean ***research***: The systematic investigation into and study of materials and sources in order to establish facts and reach new conclusions. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/research

Comment: "Precis" is the French loan word that means summary.

Comment: The French variant for summary is "résumé", not recherché.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *recherché* means in French carefully searched for or researched.  In English, we know this from Proust's work *À la recherche du temps perdu*, which was mistranslated *Remembrance of Things Past* and has been corrected to *Search for Time Lost*.  English has adopted the word to mean little known or unusual or unfamiliar, i.e, something that would take a careful search to find out.

From *[Reason, Truth, and Self](https://books.google.com/books?id=cUOghhlh_M0C&pg=PA46&dq=%22recherch%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwATg8ahUKEwin44C89IzJAhWCWz4KHSpNBE4#v=onepage&q=%22recherch%C3%A9%22&f=false)* by Michael Luntley:

> We can predict the course of disease, the growth of crops. We can even
>   predict such **recherché** events as the bending of light by objects
>   with large gravitational fields and still get it all right.

Not a commonly-used word and not a substitute for *summary*.

Comment: I wouldn't call changing an untranslateable title of a book a mistranslation.  *Search for Time Lost* is also a mistranslation, in that *temps perdu* is a French [idiom](https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/temps%20perdu) that means *wasted time* (so there's a double meaning in the title: *wasted time/lost time*), and *time lost* does not have a double meaning in English.